# How to login in with Curl and SSL and cookies

Tags: php, forms, cookies, ssl, curl

I been trying to log into barnesandnoble.com mobile site with curl
and have had no luck so far.  I get back the page with no errors
and it defaults my email into the email input form box of the login page again (in the form returned from print $result).

The same code can actually let me go into ebay correctly
by changing the LOGINURL to point to ebay's login

The only difference being that barnesandnobles is https://
and ebay login was http://

Also, I believe that barnes website is asp/aspx so I don't know
how that would handle cookies and _state differently

Any help would be appreciated as I been trying to debug this for the
past 16hrs

also, my cookie.txt is writable and working

```
<?php
    $cookie_file_path = "C:/test/cookie.txt";
    $LOGINURL = "https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/mobileacct/op.asp?stage=signIn"; 
    $agent = "Nokia-Communicator-WWW-Browser/2.0 (Geos 3.0 Nokia-9000i)";

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    $headers[] = "Accept: */*";
    $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);

    $content = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch); 

    unset($ch); 

    // NAME="path_state" value="6657403">

    if(stristr($content,"path_state")){
        $array1 = explode('path_state" value="',$content);
        $content1 = $array1[1];
        $array2 = explode('">',$content1);
        $content2 = $array2[0];
    }

    $LOGINURL = "https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/mobileacct/op.asp?stage=signIn";
    $POSTFIELDS = "d_hidPageStamp=V_3_17&hidViewMode=opSignIn&stage=signIn&previousStage=mainStage&path_state=" .  $content2 . "&emailAddress=YOUREMAILHERE@gmail.com&acctPassword=YOURPASSWORD";
    $reffer = "https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/mobileacct/op.asp?stage=signIn"; 

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    $headers[] = "Accept: */*";
    $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);  

    print $result; 
?>
```

Comment: I'd be cautious about writing to the same cookie file from multiple concurrent requests.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a working example I created from your code.  This uses a function `getFormFields` that I wrote for a similar question (first reference at the bottom of this post) which logs into the Android market.

I think there may have been a couple of things in your script that were preventing the login from working.  First, you should [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) the URL parameters such as email and password in the post string (cURL will not do this for you).  Second, I think the `x` value used as part of the login URL may be required.

Here is a solution that logs in successfully.  Note, I re-used the original cURL handle.  This is not necessary, but if you specify keep-alive, it will actually re-use the same connection, and it also saves you from having to specify the same options over and over.

Once you have the cookies, you can create a new cURL object and specify the COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR and you will be logged in without performing the first steps.

```
<?php

// options
$EMAIL            = 'you@yoursite.com';
$PASSWORD         = 'yourpassword';
$cookie_file_path = "/tmp/cookies.txt";
$LOGINURL         = "https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/mobileacct/op.asp?stage=signIn"; 
$agent            = "Nokia-Communicator-WWW-Browser/2.0 (Geos 3.0 Nokia-9000i)";


// begin script
$ch = curl_init(); 

// extra headers
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";

// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);

// execute session to get cookies and required form inputs
$content = curl_exec($ch); 

// grab the hidden inputs from the form required to login
$fields = getFormFields($content);
$fields['emailAddress'] = $EMAIL;
$fields['acctPassword'] = $PASSWORD;

// get x value that is used in the login url
$x = '';
if (preg_match('/op\.asp\?x=(\d+)/i', $content, $match)) {
    $x = $match[1];
}

//$LOGINURL   = "https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/mobileacct/op.asp?stage=signIn";
  $LOGINURL   = "https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/mobileacct/op.asp?x=$x";

// set postfields using what we extracted from the form
$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 

// change URL to login URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS); 

// perform login
$result = curl_exec($ch);  

print $result; 


function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form action="op.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        die('didnt find login form');
    }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}
```

This worked for me, hope that helps get you going.

Here are some other cURL answer I have that may help learn:

- [Retrieve Android Market mylibrary with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958495/retrieve-android-market-mylibrary-with-curl/8998077#8998077)
- [multiple actions with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549892/multiple-actions-with-curl/9549990#9549990)
- [sending xml and headers via curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250702/sending-xml-and-headers-via-curl/9252130#9252130)
- [Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off/8992557#8992557)
- [Pinterest login with PHP and cURL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568948/pinterest-login-with-php-and-curl-not-working)

Comment: Drew, this answer helped me get the answer to my own question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611362/curl-login-into-ebay-co-uk/16614760#16614760 I hope you don't mind, but I used some of you code. :)

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov Totally fine, glad it was helpful!  I see you even provided very nice credit so I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Tried several other solutions, none worked. Used your's and at last got what I needed. Thanks a million...

Comment: The only thing I would change about this is how you set your email and password fields. I prefer to just have another associative array that overrides the $Fields array if that field exists. It just makes it easier if you need to add other overrides later, instead of adding two more lines, you just need to add another value to the override array. If that particular field is removed from the form, it will just be ignored.

foreach($Form['fields'] as $Name => $Value){
 if(isset($Account[$Name])) $Form['fields'][$Name] = $Account[$Name];
}