# eBay login using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to cURL and I'm trying to access my ebay account using php cURL, I have an existing code but ebay doesn't seem to let me log in using cURL. It just displays the login page when I echo the result.

```
$username="testtest"; 
$password="testtest"; 
$url="https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?co_partnerId=2&siteid=3&UsingSSL=1"; 

$gacookie="/var/www/barcode/cookie/cookie.txt";
$postdata = 'userid='. $username .':pass='. $password;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $gacookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $gacookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$AskApache_result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

echo $AskApache_result;
```

Is it possible to login to ebay using php cURL by username and password or tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post data should look like this:

`foo=bar&field=value`

In your case:

`$postdata = 'userid='. $username .'&pass='. $password;`

Comment: Hi Skpd, still doesn't let me log in.

Comment: It was just a data format. Fields that you need exactly you can find on https://signin.ebay.co.uk page in `<form>` tag. You need to send all inputs with proper data.

Comment: won't work if $username/$password contains special characters like &= or space. use urlencode() or http_build_query(), `$postdata = 'userid='. urlencode($username) .'&pass='. urlencode($password);`

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

and troubleshoot further with

```
var_dump($AskApache_result);
echo curl_error($ch);
```

Comment: tried but didn't work. Also echo curl_error($ch); didn't display any errors.

Comment: check this post if it helps..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307744/how-to-login-in-with-curl-and-ssl-and-cookies