# cURL login into ebay.co.uk

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying for some time now to use cURL to login to eBay.co.uk. The cookies are being set and the post data is being sent correctly however I am not sure that the cookie file is being read again or even set correctly for that matter since I'm getting a page from eBay that says I need to enable cookies in my browser.

Here is the cURL class I'm using:

```
class Curl {
    private $ch;
    private $cookie_path;
    private $agent;

    public function __construct($userId) {
        $this->cookie_path = dirname(realpath(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))).'/cookies/' . $userId . '.txt';
        $this->agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
    }

    private function init() {
        $this->ch = curl_init();
    }

    private function close() {
        curl_close ($this->ch);
    }

    private function setOptions($submit_url) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agent); 
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        //curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_path);         
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_path);
    }

    public function curl_cookie_set($submit_url) {
        $this->init();
        $this->setOptions($submit_url);
        $result = curl_exec ($this->ch);
        $this->close();
        return $result;
    }

    public function curl_post_request($referer, $submit_url, $data) {
        $this->init();
        $this->setOptions($submit_url);
        $post = http_build_query($data);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        $result = curl_exec ($this->ch);
        $this->close();
        return $result;
    }

    public function curl_clean() {
        // cleans and closes the curl connection
        if (file_exists($this->cookie_path)) { 
            unlink($this->cookie_path); 
        }
        if ($this->ch != '') { 
            curl_close ($this->ch);
        }
    }    
}
```

Here is the test script, the login details are for a throwaway account, so feel free to test with them:

```
$curl = new Curl(md5(1));   //(md5($_SESSION['userId']));
$referer = 'http://ebay.co.uk';
$submit_url = "http://signin.ebay.co.uk/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll";

$data['userid'] = "VitoGambino-us";
$data['pass'] = "P0wqw12vi";
$data['MfcISAPICommand'] = 'SignInWelcome';
$data['siteid'] = '0';
$data['co_partnerId'] = '2';
$data['UsingSSL'] = '0';
$data['ru'] = '';
$data['pp'] = '';
$data['pa1'] = '';
$data['pa2'] = '';
$data['pa3'] = '';
$data['i1'] = '-1';
$data['pageType'] = '-1';


$curl->curl_cookie_set($referer);
$result = $curl->curl_post_request($referer, $submit_url, $data);

echo $result;
```

Here is what the cookie files contents are:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.ebay.co.uk  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  BDE9B23B829CA7DF2CC4D5880F5173A6
.ebay.co.uk TRUE    /   FALSE   0   ebay    %5Esbf%3D%23%5Ecv%3D15555%5E
.ebay.co.uk TRUE    /   FALSE   1431871451  dp1 bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**53776c5b^
#HttpOnly_.ebay.co.uk   TRUE    /   FALSE   0   s   CgAD4ACBRl4pbYjJjZDk1YTAxM2UwYTU2YjYzYzRhYmU0ZmY2ZjcyODYBSgAXUZeKWzUxOTYzOGI5LjMuMS43LjY2LjguMC4xuMWzLg**
.ebay.co.uk TRUE    /   FALSE   1400335451  nonsession  CgADLAAFRlj/jMgDKACBa/DpbYjJjZDk1YTAxM2UwYTU2YjYzYzRhYmU0ZmY2ZjcyODcBTAAXU3dsWzUxOTYzOGI5LjMuMS42LjY1LjEuMC4xhVUTMQ**
.ebay.co.uk TRUE    /   FALSE   1526479451  lucky9  4551358
```

Comment: You know they have an API, right? Why do you want to access eBay via cURL?

Comment: I'm aware of eBay API and I know it very well, I need to cURL into eBay to perform actions that API doesn't do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

eBay uses a pretty tricky method for logging in. It's a combination of cookies, hidden fields and a javascript redirect after successful login.

Here's how I solved it.

Newly modified class:

```
class Curl {
    private $ch;
    private $cookie_path;
    private $agent;

    // userId will be used later to keep multiple users logged
    // into ebay site at one time.
    public function __construct($userId) {
        $this->cookie_path = dirname(realpath(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))).'/cookies/' . $userId . '.txt';
        $this->agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
    }

    private function init() {
        $this->ch = curl_init();
    }

    private function close() {
        curl_close ($this->ch);
    }

    // Set cURL options
    private function setOptions($submit_url) {
        $headers[] = "Accept: */*";
        $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->agent); 
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_path);         
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_path);
    }

    // Grab initial cookie data
    public function curl_cookie_set($submit_url) {
        $this->init();
        $this->setOptions($submit_url);
        curl_exec ($this->ch);
        echo curl_error($this->ch);
    }  

    // Grab hidden fields
    public function get_form_fields($submit_url) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
        $result = curl_exec ($this->ch);
        echo curl_error($this->ch);
        return $this->getFormFields($result);
    }

    // Send login data
    public function curl_post_request($referer, $submit_url, $data) {
        $post = http_build_query($data);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        $result =  curl_exec ($this->ch);
        echo curl_error($this->ch);
        $this->close();
        return $result;
    }    

    // Show the logged in "My eBay" or any other page
    public function show_page( $submit_url) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
        $result =  curl_exec ($this->ch);
        echo curl_error($this->ch);
        return $result;
    }

    // Used to parse out form
    private function getFormFields($data) {
        if (preg_match('/(<form name="SignInForm".*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
            $inputs = $this->getInputs($matches[1]);
            return $inputs;
        } else {
            die('Form not found.');
        }
    }

    // Used to parse out hidden field names and values
    private function getInputs($form) {
        $inputs = array();
        $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

        if ($elements > 0) {
            for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
                $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

                if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                    $name  = $name[1];
                    $value = '';

                    if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                        $value = $value[1];
                    }

                    $inputs[$name] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $inputs;
    }

    // Destroy cookie and close curl.
    public function curl_clean() {
        // cleans and closes the curl connection
        if (file_exists($this->cookie_path)) { 
            unlink($this->cookie_path); 
        }
        if ($this->ch != '') { 
            curl_close ($this->ch);
        }
    }    
}
```

The actual code in use:

```
$curl = new Curl(md5(1));   //(md5($_SESSION['userId']));
$referer = 'http://ebay.com';
$formPage = 'http://signin.ebay.com/aw-cgi/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn';

// Grab cookies from main page, ebay.com
$curl->curl_cookie_set($referer);

// Grab the hidden form fields and then set UsingSSL = 0
// Login with credentials and hidden fields
$data = $curl->get_form_fields($formPage);
$data['userid'] = "";
$data['pass'] = "";
$data['UsingSSL'] = '0';

// Post data to login page. Don't echo this result, there's a
// javascript redirect. Just do this to save login cookies
$formLogin = "https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?co_partnerId=2&amp;siteid=3&amp;UsingSSL=0";
$curl->curl_post_request($referer, $formLogin, $data);

// Use login cookies to load the "My eBay" page, viola, you're logged in.
$result = $curl->show_page('http://my.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?MyeBay');

// take out Javascript so it won't redirect to actualy ebay site
echo str_replace('<script', '<', $result);
```

I used some of the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307744/how-to-login-in-with-curl-and-ssl-and-cookies), thanks to [drew010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892493/drew010)!

Comment: you better hide your username and password credintials

Comment: It's a throwaway account I made just for this, so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: anyone knows if this is still working?

Comment: impressive, but i hope you'll learn to use DOMDocument & DOMXPath instead of regex html parsing next time :) (--signed someone who has made a [facebook login script](https://github.com/divinity76/msgme), a [gmail login script](https://gist.github.com/divinity76/544d7cadd3e88e057ea3504cb8b3bf7e), a Google Data Studio login script, a hotmail login script, and lots of similar stuff)

Comment: @hanshenrik I posted this 6 years ago... I've graduated to parsing HTML with regex.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454