# Grabbing HTML from a page only a logged in user can access?

Tags: php, facebook, web, https

Essentially I want to grab some data from a web page that only a logged in user can see i.e. Facebook analytics and Page insights.

If I query the specific page and try to grab it normally, it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you have credentials to login to the site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307744/how-to-login-in-with-curl-and-ssl-and-cookies

Comment: Yes I have the login credentials, thanks for the link Karl, I'll have a look now.

Comment: FYI: Scraping is explicitly against Facebook’s ToS.

Answer (score 1):

Use CURL and cookie session to login to the page remotely

using these options:

```
$url = 'https://somewhere.com';
$post['user'] = 'myuser';
$post['pass'] = 'mypass';
$ch = curl_init( );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count( $post ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $post ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');

echo $result = curl_exec($ch); // Outputs HTML response from url
```

*Take note that posts name vary from the site your trying to login.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this successfully.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array('header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"))
));
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```