# Cant get websites content through cURL - need to be logged in

Tags: php, authentication, curl, cookies

I am trying to get the contents of a webpage through cURL.

However, unless logged into the game [Bin Weevils](http://play.binweevils.com), the contents of the page will simply be `failed=99`.

I used the free Chrome extension [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) to find out which cookie out of the ones that are set when you log into Bin Weevils is required to view the page and discovered that it is the cookie `PHPSESSID`. I have attempted to set this cookie in the cURL header, but with no avail - `failed=99` is still displayed in the output.

This is the cURL code which I am currently using:

```
<?php
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
         'PHPSESSID: removed for privacy'
    ));
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch); 
      echo $output;
?>
```

If I visit the page when not signed in to Bin Weevils and simply use EditThisCookie to set the cookie PHPSESSID, the page content shows.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve these things first you need to authenticate using user name and password via cURL.

Step:1)
First login using cURL and retrieve cookies and store in a text file.

Step:2)
Using that cookie you can scrape that html page.

For detail example please follow these link [Scrape Page using CURL after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307744/how-to-login-in-with-curl-and-ssl-and-cookies).

Answer (score 0):

**Login to website with cURL and get secure page content**

```
    //The username  of the account.
    define('USERNAME', 'jellylion350');

    //The password of the account.
    define('PASSWORD', '123456');

    //Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
    define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');

    //Where our cookie information will be stored (needed for authentication).
    define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');

    //URL of the login form.
    define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://play.binweevils.com/game.php');

    //Login action URL. Sometimes, this is the same URL as the login form.
    define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://www.binweevils.com/membership/payment/login');


    //An associative array that represents the required form fields.
    //You will need to change the keys / index names to match the name of the form
    //fields.
    $postValues = array(
        'userID' => USERNAME,
        'password' => PASSWORD
    );

    //Initiate cURL.
    $curl = curl_init();

    //Set the URL that we want to send our POST request to. In this
    //case, it's the action URL of the login form.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);

    //Tell cURL that we want to carry out a POST request.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    //Set our post fields / date (from the array above).
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));

    //We don't want any HTTPS errors.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //Where our cookie details are saved. This is typically required
    //for authentication, as the session ID is usually saved in the cookie file.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

    //Sets the user agent. Some websites will attempt to block bot user agents.
    //Hence the reason I gave it a Chrome user agent.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

    //Tells cURL to return the output once the request has been executed.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    //Allows us to set the referer header. In this particular case, we are 
    //fooling the server into thinking that we were referred by the login form.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);

    //Do we want to follow any redirects?
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

    //Execute the login request.
    curl_exec($curl);

    //Check for errors!
    if(curl_errno($curl)){
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
    }

    //We should be logged in by now. Let's attempt to access a password protected page
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');

    //Use the same cookie file.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

    //Use the same user agent, just in case it is used by the server for session validation.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

    //We don't want any HTTPS / SSL errors.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    //Execute the GET request and print out the result.
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
     $result = urldecode($result); //decode url
     // get result as expected
      $data = explode('&',$result);
      $final_data =array();
      foreach($data as  $row){
          $temp = explode('=',$row);
          $final_data[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
      }
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($final_data);
```

Output of page is as follow

```
[res] => 1
[idx] => ########              //hiden for security purpose
[weevilDef] => ############### //hiden for security purpose
[level] => 70
[tycoon] => 0
[lastLog] => 1970-01-01+00%3A00%3A00
[dateJoined] => 2015-02-09+11%3A07%3A00
[x] => y
```

`

For detail [read this](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-login-to-website-with-curl/)