# Login to site using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to using cURL and its hard to find good resources for it. What I'm trying to do is login to a remote site, by having curl do the login form and then send back that it was successful.

```
//username and password of account
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypassword';

//login form action url
$url="http://watchers.to/"; 
$postinfo = "op=login&login=".$username."&password=".$password;

$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) 
Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://watchers.to/?op=my_reports");
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
echo $html;
curl_close($ch);
```

What am I doing wrong. After this is working I want to redirect to another page and get content from my site.

Comment: your login session is lost after the first curl

Comment: could you explain how to fix.

Comment: you can't fix it,it's not broken

Comment: so you are saying there is no solution to it ?

Comment: @1337 you will need to pass the cookies from the first response to the second curl,i am not sure this will work, it depends on the authentication implementation,remote server setting, etc

Comment: still waiting for solution im newbie here.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Here are numerous examples of using PHP and curl to log into sites and navigate around once logged in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307956/892493