# Post Request in php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a login php post but its not posting correctly... i need the following sent to the Curl but its just not sending

```
//Set the post parameters 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'j_username='.$username.'&j_password='.$password.'&tk_trp ='.$tk_trp);
```

Is what i am  currently trying to use and its just not taking is there something anyone notices that i am doing wrong? Any advice would be great thanks!

I have been stuck on this a good while now and its just not coming together for me so thought i would reach out :)

```
  <?php
    $token = GetStringBetween(getURL("tokenlocatonurl"),"start'", "'");
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $username = 'myuser';
    $password = 'mypass';
    $tk_trp = '$token';
    $loginUrl = 'lognurlhere';

        function getURL($u){
            $u = file_get_contents("http://{$u}");
            return $u != false ? $u : "";
        }
        function GetStringBetween($string, $start, $finish){
            $string = " ".$string;
            $position = strpos($string, $start);
            if ($position == 0) return "";
            $position += strlen($start);
            $length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
            return substr($string, $position, $length);
        }

    //init curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    //Set the URL to work with
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

    // ENABLE HTTP POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //Set the post parameters  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'j_username='.$username'&j_password='.$password'&tk_trp='.$tk_trp');

    //Handle cookies for the login
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

    //Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
    //not to print out the results of its query.
    //Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
    //from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //execute the request (the login)
    $store = curl_exec($ch);

    //the login is now done and you can continue to get the
    //protected content.

    //set the URL to the protected file
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url to grab content from');

    //execute the request
    $content = curl_exec($ch);



    ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't sending the request or it just doesn't login and save cookie? Do you see any errors?

Comment: Does not login. nope no errors

Comment: Check your `cookie.txt` file and see if your code creates the file

Comment: It didnt make one

Comment: Yeah its not creating a cookie file so wierd

Comment: Change `'cookie.txt'` to `''`. I updated my answer. Check it

Comment: from my experience, postfields should be an array of key => value (i.e. `array('username' => 'value1', 'password' => 'password', timeout => 2);` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I see with your code are:

- You should use `http_build_query` to encode your data.
- You should enable `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`.
- You should disable `CURLOPT_POST` AFTER you logged in.
- It's better to use a user agent because some sites block suspicious user agents.
- Use both `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and use `'-'` to store it in memory.

Here is final code:

```
<?php
$data = [
    'j_username' => $username,
    'j_password' => $password,
    'tk_trp' => $tk_trp
];
$ch = curl_init("http://example.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '-');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '-');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/dashboard");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
$x = curl_exec($ch);
echo $x;
```

Comment: I added the full code to my question how would i make them go together?

Comment: Still isnt working but im not sure im combining my code with your data code correctly

Comment: This has me soooo stressed out

Comment: The code should work okay. I tested it on another page. Check this code too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307956/2570054

Comment: Its not logging in or storing cookies tho its outputting the page in non logged in form

Comment: @JohnSmith I updated my answer. Check the new code see if it works.

Comment: No luck with that either Hmm

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of protection on your login page. Like captcha or invisible recaptcha etc because the code above should work.

Comment: You can also provide the login url  so I can check.

Comment: there is a tk_trp token on the page that needs passed thats why i made the $tk_trp = '$stream';  and $stream = GetStringBetween(getURL("url"),"login.authToken = '", "'"); part Hmm im new to Stack is there a way to DM? ill send you the login and everything if there is

Comment: I don't think there is any DM feature in here. But in line 7 of your code I saw `$tk_trp = '$token';` which is wrong. It doesn't pass `$token` data to `$tk_trp`. Please fix it and try again. Change it to `$tk_trp = $token;` (remove `'`).

Comment: Yeah its doing the same thing  im sure im just doing something very small thats breaking my code lol

Comment: Okay I just emailed.

Comment: Thanks so much! you have got it working your the best 5 star!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that extra space in &tk_trp and =  ?
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'j_username='.$username.'&j_password='.$password.'**&tk_trp =**'.$tk_trp);

Comment: What about CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? Should it be $CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS (unless it's been defined) and have an int value? Are you getting any php errors?

Comment: Try checking if this page helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224790/curl-post-format-for-curlopt-postfields